# Alternative to document in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm still new to learning next.js, but the problem is, I don't understand. How do we call an element from the written html because I want to do like the code written below?

HTML

```
<div class="container_title">
    <div class="main_title">
        <h1> Title <span>( Global )</span></h1>
        <div class="button_main_title">
            <button class="Tap_1 button" >Tap_1 </button>
            <button class="Tap_2 button">Tap_2</button>
            <button class="Tap_3 button">Tap_3</button>
            <button class="Tap_4 button">Tap_4</button>
            <button class="Tap_5 button">Tap_5</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
const main_title = document.querySelector(".main_title");
const button_main_title = document.querySelectorAll(".main_title button");

(() => {
  main_title.addEventListener('click', event => {
       if(event.target.classList.contains("button")){
          for(i=0;i<button_main_title.length;i++) button_main_title[i].classList.remove("active");    
         event.target.classList.add("active")  
        }
    })
})();
const Firsr_BTN = document.querySelector(".button_main_title .button:first-child");
Firsr_BTN.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

NextJS is a framework which is based on React, which is based on Javascript. However, the only way that I know to *select* an element is to use a React hook called `useRef`. Let me give you an example.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

const YourComponent = () => {
    const myHeading = useRef()
    console.log('heading', myHeading)

  return (
   <div>
     <h1 ref={myHeading}>Heading</h1>
   </div>
  )

}
```

Now you have your `h1` as `myHeading` and you can modify it the way you want. Always check your console for what's the element object looks like and how to edit it.

Comment: `QuerySelector` and and other `DOM traversing methods` are from Vanilla JS and they do not work in React.